# Dropdown list in notification area

Tags: android, list, listview, notifications

Is it possible to show notification (let's say incoming messages) which is convertible into into list of notifications. Like ordinary drop down list in user interface.

E.g.

1. App shows 5 incoming messages as 1 notification
2. When user selects notification it converted into list containing 5 notifications
3. Now user can select one of 5 notifications and open specific one

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont see why not.
You make an activity that creates the list of notifications, and then you make a notification that links to that activity?
Though it will probably not be pretty. it will function.

Comment: It's workable, but it's not good idea - to generate once more 5 notifications after opening 1 "main" notification...

Comment: I know, I'd suggest you bundle your notifications into 1 in the notification menu, and when that is pressed, open an activity with the bundles notifications, from where the user can then press the notification he/she'd like to watch.
That is the best solution android offers imho.